# How to Get Rid of Duplicate Counts in Hive/Impala

Tags: sql, hive, impala, hue

I am trying to count the total values for a specific column for three tables in Impala/Hive, but I can only seem to get the total values for each table. For example, I am receiving the count for Poland for each table instead of the count for Poland for all three tables combined. I have tried to union the tables together, but I have been unsuccessful. Listed below is the coding I have used.

```
SELECT table1.country, COUNT(*)  
FROM table1 
GROUP BY table1.country  
UNION 
SELECT table2.country, COUNT(*) 
FROM table2 
GROUP BY table2.country 
UNION 
SELECT table3.country, COUNT(*)  
FROM table3
GROUP BY table3.country
ORDER BY COUNT(country) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```
SELECT table1.country, COUNT(*)  
FROM table1 
GROUP BY table1.country  
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.country, COUNT(*) 
FROM table2 
GROUP BY table2.country 
UNION ALL
SELECT table3.country, COUNT(*)  
FROM table3
GROUP BY table3.country
ORDER BY COUNT(country) DESC;
```

`UNION` removes duplicates, so if two tables have the same count for a country, then the duplicate is removed.

EDIT:

If you want one row per country, use a subquery and reaggregate:

```
SELECT country, SUM(cnt)
FROM (SELECT table1.country, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY table1.country  
      UNION ALL
      SELECT table2.country, COUNT(*) 
      FROM table2 
      GROUP BY table2.country 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT table3.country, COUNT(*)  
      FROM table3
      GROUP BY table3.country
     ) t
GROUP BY country;
```

Comment: I received the same result unfortunately.

Comment: @KarlYujeck . . . That would also happen if Poland where not in all the tables.

Comment: The biggest issue I am having is duplicate counts. I need help removing the duplicates.

Comment: It generally more transparent for optimisation to `UNION ALL` all the tables and then do `COUNT` on all dataset than sum up individual counts (as I see, for example, for Oracle and Postgres, but cannot tell about Impala)

Comment: @astentx . . . Actually, in most databases, I don't think that is true for two reasons.  First, multiple aggregations on smaller data is likely to be faster than one aggregation on larger data (due to the O(n log n) nature of aggregation algorithms).  Second, individual group bys are more likely to make use of indexes (which is not an issue for Hive).  Oracle has a pretty smart optimizer, so it might work there.  But I wouldn't say in general that `union all` followed by aggregation is going to have better performance.